# Sorting numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have numbers I am trying to sort in a table. Some are single digit. Some are 2 digit and some are 3 digit. I would like to sort them either smallest to largest or vice versa. ( It doesn't matter.) The options for sorting are only A to Z or Z to A, not " smallest to largest," etc. when I sort the numbers, they are all mixed up because of the second or third digit. How do I change the mechanism to sort from A to Z to smallest to largest?

Comment: Your numbers are saved as text and need to be converted to numbers.

Comment: Scott is correct about it being text. If you want it to stay text, then add a column and use a formula to convert the text to a value =+TEXT(E7,"###") would convert text in e7 to its numeric equivalent

Comment: What do you mean smallest to largest? 1 is smaller than 11...

Answer (score 0):

Given **text** values in column **A** like:

[image]

and you sort them you will get:

[image]

This is not good.

In **B1** enter:

```
=--A1
```

and copy down.  Then copy column **B** and PasteSpecialValues onto column **A**.

If you now sort column **A** you will get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the Sorting functionality in Excel, it gives you the dialog for telling it your sort keys and orders. You then tell it to perform.

If it detects numeric-looking data in cells in the sort range's sort key columns (or rows if doing a horizontal sort), it will ask if it should treat the data AS numbers or not:

[Treat Numbers as Numbers? Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyFjS.png)

(Not MY choice for that to be a link, not a pic.)

That only happens if a cell's entire content is numeric-looking, so "823 North Madison" will sort as text either way while "823" alone would be sorted as a number.

Just select the first choice, as shown, and your values will sort as desired. It will have no effect upon actual text in the range sorted, except that, as the numbers are treated as numbers, they will sort first for an A-z sort.

The choice "persists" at least during the current Excel session. So I usually engage Sort again, immediately, and change the choice back if I choose the lower choice for a sort, then escape the function before actually sorting again.

If, on the other hand, you DO want to make Excel stop considering the numeric-looking material as text, there are EASILY half-a-dozen common ways to approach it which may or may not fit your data and more importantly, usually, where it came from. Stuff scraped from the web often takes extra work due to garbage characters (from our point of view, once in Excel:  we loved those characters on the webpages themselves as they made for easy viewing of the material... just hate them now) laced throughout the digits and such.